# pipe all requests to a particular port - node js application

Tags: node.js, apache, server, httpd.conf, proxypass

I am trying to run `node js` and `apache` in a same server for that

I am trying to pipe all requests to a particular port (eg: example.com:80 to example.com:3000).

For that, I changed httpd.conf file located in "`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`"

**Added these lines st the end**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted using `sudo service httpd restart`

but **nothing changed.**

There are more 2 httpd.conf files available **->**

```
/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

at the end of `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file I saw *this:*

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
#
#   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#   DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED.  USE INCLUDE FILES IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE
#   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
#
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

I cannot understand the line `USE INCLUDE FILES IF YOU NEED TO MAKE A CHANGE`.

**What should I do????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer Nginx over Apache2 but you can use any of them.

for apache2 you should enable `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then you should add a config file for apache usually named `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`:
(you can remove Directory part if you don't need it)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com

   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyVia Full
   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>

   <Location / >
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
   </Location>

    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/html">
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then enable the config and restart apache2 with:

```
sudo a2ensite example.com
sudo services apache2 restart
```

for Nginx config you should add these lines to `/etc/nginx/site-available/your-app.conf`:

```
upstream app {
server 0.0.0.0:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-error.log info;
}
```

then you should run:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and then:

```
# remove default config symlink from sites-enabled dir
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
# test if config is OK:
sudo nginx -t
# restart the nginx:
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

---

P.S: I used the apache conf example from [this](https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/application/misc/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/) link

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used Apache2 in a while as I would usually use Nginx to proxy my Node.JS applications.

You should copy the default site config from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. (Command: `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf`).

Then place the configuration that you have there into the new file. Edit what needs editing then enable the new site configuration by running `sudo a2ensite mysite.com.conf`. Then restart the apache2 process by running `sudo service apache2 restart`.

You should now be able to test it and it should work if your configuration syntax is correct.

Comment: This `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`file does not exist, should I create both files??

Comment: @HelloWorld It is strange that the default site configuration file does not exist. Is there a default Apache page shown when you try to access the server IP?

Comment: I don't know much about apache or other like nginx. But I restart and do stuff like changing the port or any other config by running **httpd** command. (eg: `service httpd restart`);